# Pandas rolling transpose?

Tags: pandas

Is it possible in pandas to transpose rolling window into row?

[pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

```
>> df
    Close
0   3.69 
1   9.14 
2   9.49 
3   15.84
4   17.00
5   26.31
```

There is tolling operation in pandas that can give me last N values I want to transpose, but how I can to insert them in to the row?

```
>> df
    Close    1       2      3 
0   3.69     NaN     NaN    NaN
1   9.14     3.69    NaN    NaN
2   9.49     9.14    3.69   NaN
3   15.84    9.49    9.14   3.69
4   17.00    15.84   9.49   9.14
5   26.31    17.00   15.84  9.49
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
N = 3
for x in range(1, N + 1):
    df[x] = df['Close'].shift(x)
print (df)
   Close      1      2     3
0   3.69    NaN    NaN   NaN
1   9.14   3.69    NaN   NaN
2   9.49   9.14   3.69   NaN
3  15.84   9.49   9.14  3.69
4  17.00  15.84   9.49  9.14
5  26.31  17.00  15.84  9.49
```

Because [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) use some aggregate function like `sum`:

```
N = 3
for x in range(1, N + 1):
    df[x] = df['Close'].rolling(x+1).sum()
print (df)
   Close      1      2      3
0   3.69    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   9.14  12.83    NaN    NaN
2   9.49  18.63  22.32    NaN
3  15.84  25.33  34.47  38.16
4  17.00  32.84  42.33  51.47
5  26.31  43.31  59.15  68.64
```

Comment: pandas requires some mind shift to use it efficiently :) thx!

Comment: @AlexT - Glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([df1.shift(i) for i in range(4)],axis=1)

   Close  Close  Close  Close
0   3.69    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   9.14   3.69    NaN    NaN
2   9.49   9.14   3.69    NaN
3  15.84   9.49   9.14   3.69
4  17.00  15.84   9.49   9.14
5  26.31  17.00  15.84   9.49
```